# How to ask Cmake output googletest detailed result

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

Normally, if I type `make test` with the cmake generated makefile, it will show something like this:

```
    Start 1: UnitTest
1/2 Test #1: UnitTest .........................***Failed    0.01 sec
    Start 2: PerfTest
2/2 Test #2: PerfTest .........................   Passed    0.01 sec

50% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - UnitTest (Failed)
```

But what if I want to see the real output from googletest, which tells me exactly what failed? Is there a way to force cmake/ctest spit it out?

UPDATE: now I know I can type `ctest -V` to show detailed output, but how can I achieve the same using `make test`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out I can do this:

```
make test ARGS=-V
```

Answer (score -1):

you can take a look to **Testing** directory on your build directory.

Hope this helps.